# C# dataGridView shows no data

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

there are many posts about this, but no one helped me. Maybe i have just a logical problem or something like this. I'am a C# newbie.

So following problem. I have a dataGridView in Form1. When i click button1 Form6 appears, i give in a table name and fillDataGrid-mehtod runs in Form1. But. shows no Data the dataGradview just keeps empty with nothing in it.

Now the curios thing, if i place the Code from fillDataGrid-method in the button1 method every thing works fine.

Database (SQLite) connection works fine (not shown in the code example).

**FORM1:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form6 f6 = new Form6();
    f6.Show();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 createTable = new Form3();
    createTable.Show();         
}

public void fillDataGrid(String Eingabe)
{
    String tabelle = Eingabe;               
    String selectCommand = "select ID, VON, BIS, DAUER, KOMMENTAR from " + tabelle + ";";

    SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectCommand, sqlite_conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    //dataGridView1.DataBindings.Clear();
    //dataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); 
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

**FORM6:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    String Eingabe = textBox5.Text;

    f1.fillDataGrid(Eingabe);
    Hide();
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new Form1 object, but never showing it.  The new form1 object is NOT the form1 object you clicked to Form6 from.

Comment: @LarsTech I just noticed that it was WinForms sorry

Comment: I would also suggest moving this function/method out to it's own class or utils.cs file you are going to run into tons of confusion and duplicated efforts trying to call methods in Parent forms from child forms `public void fillDataGrid(String Eingabe)` change the method signature from void to DataTable and create a separate static class also wrap your sql objects around a `using(){}`

Comment: OH jesus, jeah thanks, searched for an hour and have totally overseen it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You never show this form:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
```

So there's nothing to display.  If you want to display the grid on the *already existing* form then you need to use *that* one, not a *new* one.

Since `Form6` has a dependency on an instance of `Form1`, require that dependency in the constructor:

```
private Form1 Form1Instance { get; set; }

public Form6(Form1 form1Instance)
{
    Form1Instance = form1Instance;
}
```

Then when you create your instance of `Form6`, supply that dependency:

```
Form6 f6 = new Form6(this);
f6.Show();
```

Then in `Form6` you can use that instance to show the grid:

```
String Eingabe = textBox5.Text;
Form1Instance.fillDataGrid(Eingabe);
Hide();
```